# Is it wrong to apply to a job posting if I'm not going to be around for the next month to interview?

Tags: job-search

I saw a job posting I like and I would like to apply. However I will be away on vacation for the next month so I will not be able to answer phone calls or attend interviews during that time (different side of the world). So from that point of view it seems like a waste of everyone's time.

On the other hand I don't want to miss out on the opportunity.

Is this something I can work around using my cover letter or something? Or is the recommended course of action just to wait until I return and apply then?

Comment: What is the application process for this job?

Comment: @mcknz, pretty standard fill out form and attach resume.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, 12 hour time difference makes it difficult to line up with both sides being awake at the same time.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I just said it would be difficult, not that I'm completely unwilling to work with it. However, in my past experience, HR calls in the middle of the day, which would for me be the middle of the night. I don't know how I could possibly make a good impression if I was awoken by a phone call.

Comment: I've *never* been called from HR as a first contact, at least not in the last 25 years... it's always been via email, with a request to set up a time for a call/interview/whatever. If you reach that point, then they're already interested, so you can explain your situation then.

Comment: @MikeHarris, I have always had HR call first. I have even had one call and immediately do an interview (which didn't go well because who does that?). Maybe it depends on the country or industry, but I have never had them not call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few factors to this equation.

It will depend on how long the hiring process usually takes at this company and how quickly the company plans to fill the position (Unfortunately you will have no way of knowing either of these, unless they stipulated). Often companies can take a more than a few weeks sifting through resumes.

Also, how badly do you want in on this opportunity? If you really want in I'm sure you could make a plan to enable roaming on your phone while abroad for phone calls.  If it comes to it and they really like your resume, I'm sure they would be willing to phone you in designated time frames (for example between 08:30 & 10:30 local time) or do the initial interview via Skype if necessary.  Just state clearly what they need to be aware of in your cover letter.

You have nothing to lose by applying.  Just state clearly in your cover letter what your circumstances are and will be for the next month so you don't waste anybody's time.

Comment: Roaming isn't an issue, the issue is 12 hour time difference (e.g. I'm not picking up the phone in the middle of the night). I might apply.. But I might just take this time to brush up on some concepts and hope the position is still open when I come back. Thanks!

Comment: @Catsunami: if the position isn't important enough to answer an interview call in the middle of the night then it's not important enough to put your application in.

Comment: a 12 hour time difference isn't unsurmountable, at some point it is 6pm and 6am in each place, if you want the job 6am isn't pout of the question for answering the phone.  This is a fanatical time.

Comment: @WendyG, 6am is not a problem for me, but for a lot of companies 6pm is a problem. I know at my current job we do not do conference calls after 5pm, it's pretty much company policy. We also don't do calls before 8am. I think it's a fanatical time for some industries, certainly not for mine. My concern is obviously that HR would call me while I was asleep without any prior warning - even if I wake up, I might not be coherent enough to make a surprise good impression.

Comment: You could always state that you will only be available between 08:30 and say 10:30 which would be 20:30 and 22:30 which would still be reasonable.

Comment: @JustSaying, that's good advice. I never thought that was something I could put into my cover letter/application. You should add it to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

My daughter just started a job.  She was in the middle east (Amman, Jordan) studying when applying and interviewing for a job back here in the states.

The application was on-line.  The three interviews were done via Skype.  She had an offer contingent on passing a drug test which could only be done here.

So yes, it's possible.  Depends on the company.  You won't know until you ask.

Happy job hunting.

Answer (score 1):

In my area it is common to provide a telephone number with the job offer for "upcoming questions". Your case seems to fit here.

They can tell you more about the hiring process and your opportunities to join it, either during your vacation or after it.

After collecting this information, it will be more easy to make decision like JustSaying suggests.

To answer your question

> Is it wrong to apply to a job posting if I'm not going to be around for the next month to interview?

No, it is not! It is never wrong, maybe awkward sometimes.